# 403 Forbidden after change of base URL

Tags: magento-1.9, error, base-url

I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error on one of my Magento webshops. It is a multi-shop Magento installation. For the main/base webshop I have created a new version, so the main/base URL's had to be changed for the old version.

The old version now has a dummy/test domainname as Base URL but it is giving me a 403 Forbidden error. This is frustrating because I need to be able to access the backend to see orders and information on the other webshops wich are running on this multi-store Magento installation.

***Situation:***

**OLD SERVER:**

DOMAINS:

- main.nl <- This is replaced by test/dummy.nl which now gives a 403
- sub1.nl
- sub2.nl

**NEW SERVER**

DOMAINS:

- other main.nl
- main.nl (domain migrated from old server to new magento installation)

Comment: Still haven't found the solution is there somebody who can help?

Comment: i'm also experiencing the same problem, in my case, some files on pub/media/ (ex: http://example.com/pub/static/version1594835608/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.css) returns error 403. i've been stuck on this problem for more than 2 days

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was due to a recent change to theme and composer update.

Go to `/pub/static/` and delete everything except `.htaccess`. Do the same for `/var/` (exclude backups folder if you have backups).

Answer (score -1):

You need change permission 755 for folder and 644 for file.

Comment: But there hasn't been changes to the permissions. The only thing that changed was the Base URL.